# Can uncountably many points on the boundary conformally map to a single one?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am not sure I understand the answer given in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369506/riemann-mapping-under-which-uncountably-many-boundary-points-correspond-to-a-sin) question. Why is the pre-image of each ray an open interval on the unit circle? In Rudin's Real and Complex analysis we require the domain to be bounded in order to extend the conformal map to the boundary, but in that case the domain is definitely unbounded. Also, I cannot see why every 2 preimages correspondinh to 2 rays must bracket another one. I know from a book by Pommerenke that the preimage of a point on the boundary of the unit disk has measure 0, so the Cantor set is likely to make an appearance, but is there a simpler, clearer construction of a simply connected domain $\Omega$ where the extension to $\partial \Omega$ of the conformal map furnished by the Riemann Mapping Theorem maps uncountably many points in $\partial \Omega$ to a single one on $\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|=1\}$?

**Edit**

What I want is to find an example of a simply connected region $\Omega$ whose conformal map $f$ to the unit disk extends continuously to an uncountable set $E \subset \partial \Omega$ and $f(E)$ is finite.

The question I linked to has an answer which I do not really trust (some of my objections where echoed in the comments) so I am looking for an alternative (or better justified) solution.

Comment: Try breaking up the block of text to making it easier to read.

Comment: Please ask one clear question. If the question involves a function, please define this function explicitly. As it is stated, the question deals with a function from an other question (or its answer?!), the other question is a question from some Princeton skript http://web.math.princeton.edu/generals/complex13.pdf where no function appears. "*... two preimages corresponding to two rays*" is something very unclear. What does it mean that they "bracket each other" (mathematically)?! What is $\Omega$ from the next new question? Which is *the* conformal map furnished by the RMT for what function?

Comment: @dan_fulea that is the point. The other question's answer is unclear and I wanted to have some clarification on it. I will edit my question.

Comment: The linked example is correct but one key thing is missing from the explanation, namely the Caratheodory-Torhorst extension theorem which guarantees the existence of a continuous boundary extension of a Riemann mapping when the target domain has locally connected boundary. Verifying local connectivity in the linked example is an easy exercise.

Comment: @MoisheKohan So the continuity is what ensures that the preimages "bracket" each other? Is there any reference you would recommend for the Caratheodory-Torhorst thm?

Comment: I am unsure about textbook treatment, but see freely available https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309022.